# how to keep repeating word in one file and use it

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to make two applications which are identical. The difference between two apps are logo and names (and contact us page).

Consider two names are **Name 1** & **Name 2** and I want to use them everywhere. Let's say below is text I have.

```
Welcome to name_here

name_here is founded in 1987. name_here is blah blah.. name_here is blah blah...
```

Here I want to replace name_here by Name 1 and Name 2 respectively for each app.

Any idea how to get this done?

---

This is  what I did.

Create plist file as "AllInOne.plist"

and in ViewDidLoad I have

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AllInOne.plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
NSString *value1;
value1 = [savedStock objectForKey:@"lab_name"];
NSLog(@"text is ==== %@", value1);
```

That's it... Thanks a ton...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a field in the .plist of the app, something like appName, and depending on the app you put the value of that variable to Name1 or Name2.

Then the only thing you need to do is retrieve that variable from the plist.

Comment: yeah, i think this would be great option.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code.

```
#define NAME1 @"Name1"
#define NAME2 @"Name2"

  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome to %@ %@ is founded in 1987. %@ is blah blah.. %@ is blah blah...",NAME1,NAME1,NAME1,NAME1];
```

Thanks,

Comment: you need to fetch whole string "name_here" and replace with string you want from particular file.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use the localized string.

define a constant as :

```
#define MY_NAME   NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"name", @"Localizable", nil)
```

Then you add a Localizable.strings file in which you write :

```
"name" = "name1"
```

or

```
"name" = "name2"
```

(depending of your app)

Answer (score 0):

You should store the variable data (in this case NAME variables) in an external file so you can configure it per-app. It may be a JSON or plist file bundled with the app or you can fetch it over a web service etc.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you declare the name as constant and wherever the difference comes you substitute the variable instead of hardcoding the name.

```
#define name @"Name"

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome to %@. %@ is founded in 1987. %@ is this and that..."],name;
```

In your other app you define name as some other string as follows.

```
#define name @"SomeOtherName"
```

You can do the same thing with naming logos or other resources that needs to be reused. In fact, better keep a class, just to store these names and constants. So if you do it right, all you have to do is delete this class file and add another class file with the same name containing same constants but with different values stored in these constants.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a preprocessor define for each app, say APP1 and APP2.
Then, wherever you set the strings for name_here, you can stick this code:

```
#ifdef APP1
name_here = @"Company 1";
#else
name_here = @"Company 2";
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings that users see should be in a file like "Localizable.strings".

Then use:

self.title = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"App Name", @"App", @"");

Localization also allows for placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

I have not good but effective answer:

```
NSString * string = @"Welcome to name_here, name_here is founded in 1987. name_here is blah blah.. name_here is blah blah... ";
#if APP1
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"name_here" withString:APP1Text];
#else 
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"name_here" withString:APP2Text];
```